# Right Translation Map (Modular Forms)

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, number-theory, modular-forms

First I am considering the function $\tilde{f}$ : $ SL(2, \mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $\tilde{f} = (ci + d)^{-m}f(gi)$.

If $r_k$ with $k \in S0(2,\mathbb{R})$ denotes that right translation map $r_k \tilde{f}(g) = \tilde{f}(gk)$ $\forall g,k \in SL(2, \mathbb{R})$ then the set $V =$ { $r_k \tilde{f} | k \in  S0(2,\mathbb{R})$ } is a one dimensional vector space generated by $ \tilde{f}$.

I am not entirely sure how to prove that this set $V$ is a vector space generated by $ \tilde{f}$.

Comment: Only $(ci+d)^{-m}$ changes and it is multiplied by $e^{-i\theta m}$

Comment: $\{ r_k \overline{f}\}$ isn't a vector space but it generates / it is contained in the 1-dimensional vector space $\Bbb{C} \overline{f}$

Comment: so closure under addition and scalar multiplication can be proven?

Comment: how is that so?

Comment: That makes more sense. thank you

Comment: In representation theory we often confuse $G$-orbit, subrepresentation and $\Bbb{C}[G]$-submodule